# Programmatically disable CPU core

Tags: linux, multicore, processor, hardware

It is known the way to disable logical CPUs in Linux, basically with `echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<number>/online`. This way, you are only telling to the OS to ignore that given (`<number>`) CPU.

My question goes further, is it possible not only to ignore it but to turn it off physically programmatically? I want that CPU to not receive any power, in order to make its energy consumption zero.

I know that it is possible disable cores from the BIOS (not always), but I want to know whether is possible to do it within a certain program or not.

Comment: This is not a common or standard feature of SMP architectures.

Comment: @n.m. does it mean that in NUMA architectures could be possible? I did not say anything about SMP architectures, I did not know that it would be relevant

Comment: The hardware power individual cores or other components on or off may or may not exist on any particular CPU/machine model. I initially thought this feature is totally non-standard but apparently Linux started to provide a standardised interface to it recently. Google *linux power domains*.

Comment: you board is designed such that you can completely take power off of one core/chip and leave the rest of the board up?  what devices are you using for this and how are they connected to some other processor (if you turn yourself off you cant turn yourself back on so this would need to be connected to something separate unless that is how it is designed as an off only not back on thing).

Comment: what specific model, stepping, etc processor are you using and what does the datasheet say about power domains?

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747847/how-to-completely-suspend-the-processor

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you do `echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<number>/online`, what happens next depends on the particular CPU. On ARM embedded systems the kernel will typically disable the clock that drives the particular core PLL so effectively you get what you want.

On Intel X86 systems, you can only disable the interrupts and call the `hlt` instruction (which Linux Kernel does). This effectively puts CPU to the power-saving state until it is woken up by another CPU at user request. If you have a laptop, you can verify that power draw indeed goes down when you disable the core by reading the power from `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT{0,1}/current_now` (or `uevent` for all values such as voltage) or using the "powertop" utility.

For example, here's the call chain for disabling the CPU core in Linux Kernel for Intel CPUs.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c

`arch/x86/kernel/smp.c`: `smp_ops.play_dead = native_play_dead,`

`arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c` : `native_play_dead()` -> `play_dead_common()` -> `local_irq_disable()`

Before that, CPUFREQ also sets the CPU to the lowest power consumption level before disabling it though this does not seem to be strictly necessary.

`intel_pstate_stop_cpu` -> `intel_cpufreq_stop_cpu` -> `intel_pstate_set_min_pstate` -> `intel_pstate_set_pstate` -> `wrmsrl_on_cpu(cpu->cpu, MSR_IA32_PERF_CTL, pstate_funcs.get_val(cpu, pstate));`

On Intel X86 there does not seem to be an official way to disable the actual clocks and voltage regulators. Even if there was, it would be specific to the motherboard and thus your closest bet might be looking into BIOS such as coreboot.
Hmm, I realized I have no idea about Intel except looking into kernel sources.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 it became possible with new power management commands CPMINCORES CPMAXCORES.

```
Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor CPMAXCORES 50
Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor CPMINCORES 25
Powercfg -setactive scheme_current
```

Here 50% of cores are assigned for desired deep sleep, and 25% are forbidden to be parked. Very good in numeric simulations requiring increased clock rate (15% boost on Intel)

You can not choose which cores to park, but Windows 10 kernel checks Intel's Comet Lake and newer "prefered" (more power efficient) cores, and starts parking those not preferred.
It is not a strict parking, so at high load the kernel can use these cores with very low load.

just in case if you are looking for alternatives

Comment: Even though it seems an interesting option, I do not think this approach alleviates my concerns, as I need to completely _turn off_ a concrete processor or set of processors.

Comment: Technically, that is exactly what core parking do. You asked "in order to make its energy consumption zero". Generally such a complex die, or its blocks can not cut its power to zero, because there are too many logical interconnections between parts, the largest of which is cache. But that is what C6 power state does, turning off the most circuits in the specified core. Here is more on parking in WIndows https://bitsum.com/parkcontrol/

Comment: P.S. a processor and a logical core are different things. Technically, disabling one processor of many in multiprocessor system would also require disabling it power regulator. While regulators are separate, I still do not think it is possible. I am not even sure would the CPU not create a wrong damaging load impedance on the bus over QPI/UPI in unpowered state when other units are in operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get closest to this by using governors like `cpufreq`. Make Linux exclude the CPU and power saving mode will ensure that the core runs at minimal frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can also isolate cpus from the scheduler at kernel boot time.

Add `isolcpus=0,1,2` to the kernel boot parameters.

https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html

Comment: I did not know this parameter, and it is certainly interesting, even though it does not answer my question, which was to _halt_ physically a processor (receiving zero power), rather than "being ignored" by the task scheduler.

Comment: The core will receive less power. Isolating a core will reduce power consumption.

Comment: I see, but as I said, the idea is to halt completely, not to reduce power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but one way to disable the CPU is via grub config.

If you add to end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` (assuming you are using a standard Linux dist, if you are using an appliance the location of the grub config may be different), e.g.:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=".......Current config here **maxcpus**=2"
```

Then remake you grub config by running
`grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (or `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` depending on your installation). Some distros may require `nr_cpus` instead of `maxcpus`.

Just some extra info:

- If you are running a server with Multiple physical CPU then disabling one CPU may will most likely disable the memory set that is linked to that CPU, therefore it may have an effect on the performance of the server
- Disabling the CPU this way, will not effect your type 1 hypervisor from accessing the CPU (this is based on xen hypervisor, I believe it will apply to vmware as well, if anyone can provide confirmation would be great).  Depending on virtualbox setup, it may restrict the amount of CPU you can allocate to VM's unless you are running para-virtualization.
- I am unsure however if you will have any power savings, most servers and even desktops these days, already control the power well, putting to sleep any device not needed for the current load.  My concern would be by reducing the number of CPU (cores) then you will just be moving the load to the remaining CPU and due to the need to schedule the processors time, and potentially having instructions queued, and the effect of having a smaller number of cores available for interrupts (eg: network traffic), it may have a negative effect on power consumption.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK there is no system call or library function available as of now. or even ioctl implementation. So apart from creating new module / system call there are two ways I can think of :

1. using ASM `asm(<assembly code>);` where assembly code being architecture specific asm code to modify cpu flag.
2. system call in c (`man 3 system`). Assuming you just want to do it through c.

Comment: Update:- with ASM we can stop particular CPU but the kernel won't know. So it may lead complexity as kernel (scheduler) assumes CPU is working so currently there is no way except `echo > 0 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<number>/online` to inform CPU about our wish to stop thatr CPU.