# Halt instruction from Linux kernel module is not working

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86

I wrote a simple Linux kernel module to issue `hlt` instruction

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    asm("hlt");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

Loading this module on my Virtual Machine, I don't see my VM is halted.

Am I missing something?

Comment: HLT will not stop your machine. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747847/how-to-completely-suspend-the-processor and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction) to understand a bit more about these commands.

Comment: It worked, after i added asm("cli"); before asm("hlt");

Comment: Why is the other CPU's not able to service other interrupts when one CPU is down.

Comment: Probably because tasks on the other CPUs very quickly get stuck in RCU `run_on` trying to run themselves on this core.  I'd assume that interrupt handlers on other cores are still working, you just can't see any evidence of it because I/O involves mechanisms that you broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HLT` doesn't stop your machine, only make that core sleep (in C1 idle) until the next interrupt.

You can try adding `cli` instruction before `hlt`, so only an NMI can wake that CPU up and make the function return.

```
static int __init test_hello_init(void) {
    asm("cli");
    asm("hlt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't stop "the machine", only the core that executes this code.  (But as discussed in comments, that's sufficient to break enough stuff on Linux that it essentially locks up.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Shouldn't there be some sort of watchdog timer running and delivering an NMI in this case?

Comment: @fuz: oh, good point, maybe.  On bare metal, Linux likes to program one of the perf counters as an NMI watchdog.  But if you disable that to get your perf counter back, or if perf counters don't work inside a VM, there might not be any watchdog.